# jquery mobile page flicker

Tags: jquery-mobile, rhomobile

after page load and when doing listview('refresh') the page flickers.

So after transition get a flicker and after `$('#friendsList').append('#{data}').listview('refresh');` I get a flicker

tried adding

```
<style>
/*** for jquerymobile page flicker that was happending ***/
 .ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 }  
</style>
```

### EDIT

When refreshing the listview, I understand the flicker inside the listview but is it suppose to make the entire page flicker to?

### EDIT 2

If list height is > screen height page flickers.  If list height < screen height page doesn't flicker.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Its still flickering even on page load

Comment: which version of JQM are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is having the same issue as above where page flickers during transition when:

`page content height > screen height`

This is somehow related to the header/footer provided by JQM. To fix this:

1) Remove all `data-position="fixed"` from the headers/footers.

2) Include the following CSS to provide the same effect (but without flickering)

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.ui-content {
    padding-top: 57px;
    padding-bottom: 54px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.ui-footer {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for this fix for weeks. The -webkit-backface-visibility change didn't do it by itself. I needed the position fixed change as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Amulya
I did the same...although it does remove the flickering, I now face the fact that the menu bars can jump positions on the page (e.g. to the middle) and that the scrolling doesn't work as smoothly anymore: normally when scrolling and releasing the page continues to scroll for a bit and then stops, but now I scroll and when I release my finger the page instantly stops scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Remove data-position="fixed" works, but I have to keep those attribute.
Finally I fixed by change viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

Here is the link I find the answer:
[Flickering when navigating between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953753/flickering-when-navigating-between-pages)