# jQuery Mobile blinking at page transitions on iPad

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile

I have a web app built with jQuery Mobile that works fine when using it in Safari on an iPad. However, when you add it to the home screen to use it as a standalone app (with the browser navigation removed by , then the page transitions "blink" quickly after each page transition.

I have Googled on this and found that blinking was considered a bug a long time ago, and by now should be fixed. And it seems to be in Safari, but not as standalone from home screen. Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Does it have anything to do with the fact that the navigation bar is not there? It works fine as standalone on iPhone though, it's only on the iPad that it occurs...

I would accept as an answer even if someone can show me that this is a known bug (not one of the old bugs that have already been fixed, where it flickered even in Safari mode) or if someone has inside knowledge about that (no one is answering my question at the jQuery forum either...). But of course I would love it if someone actually had a workaround for the problem!

Answer (score 13):

i had exactly the same problem

http://mailinglist-archive.com/rhomobile/2011-08/00656-Re+rhomobile+page+views+and+transitions mentions something that worked for me.

```
<style>
/*** patch for jquerymobile page flicker that was happending ***/
    .ui-page {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    } 
</style>
```

I still get the flicker in the toolbar, so I converted my tool bar to :

```
<ul data-theme="b" data-role="listview" style="margin-top: 0;">
     <li data-role="list-divider">Your text goes here</li>...
```

Comment: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; fixes it for me, thanks!

Comment: if you are also targeting Android, beware of mixing -webkit-backface-visibility on a page with form elements. Sets page scrolling on "auto-pilot" once you select a text input.

Comment: Great post mate...It works fine for now! Hope is going to stay that way ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I was nervous about commenting out focus, but a google search found the following CSS that seems to work:

```
.ui-page * {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Original link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2856

I was only having a problem with the slide transition (even reverse slide worked fine.
JQ 1.7.1
JQM 1.0.1
PhoneGap 1.5.0

Comment: This did the trick for me. Such a transform, even if it's neutral, can force hardware acceleration for the element's css animations on mobile apple devices, from what I've heard.

Answer (score 3):

Revision: It should be noted that the discussion below was mitigated with the release of iOS 5.0. It can be a partial influencing factor for anyone who hasn't upgraded but if you're running 5.0, Nitro is ever present. http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/06/ios-5-brings-nitro-speed-to-home-screen-web-apps.ars

--original answer--
Apple introduced the Nitro javascript engine into the Safari browser.  However, they only installed it on the browser, not in the UIWebView (which is what you get when you run form the home screen or embedded in an application like PhoneGap.

There has been some speculation if this performance boost was omitted on purpose.  http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/apple-phonegap-html5-nitro.

So, if it seems like it's actually performing slowly...  that's cause it really is.  It's not using the Nitro engine.

Comment: Well, it isn't actually running slower, it just flickers (once) on each slide transition when used outside Safari. Very annoying, but not slow. But you mean this flicker is caused by the lack of the Nitro engine as well? If so, what does that mean for jQuery Mobile? Do you know if they are aware of this? (I cannot get a response on the jQuery forum...)

Comment: Well, it doesn't appear to be running slower because the "core animations" are built into OSX and thus iOS itself.  So, even an old iPhone 3G appears to run smoother and faster than even modern Androids.  But that's just the animations part of it. That's not really a function of the JavaScript engine. When it comes to DOM manipulations (which is what is happening as JavaScript switches which page is actually active) the JS engine starts to become really important. Depending on how taxed your processor is at the moment you can sometimes actually see the previous page, then white, then the new.

Comment: I know the JQM team is aware of the issue and have been working to address it. Unfortunately, with the state of the market of phones right now, they had to back out their change (I think around beta 2).  I will say this.  Newer Androids with dual cores like the Samsung Galaxy S2 do not have this issue. I know that doesn't help with the iPad issue you're having but it does give hope that while we're all adopting this platform right now and it may have quirks, within a year (2 at the most) the newest crop of smart devices will eliminate this issue.  Build for the future. Devices catch up quickly

Comment: Of course the speculation was unfounded. In iOS 5 Nitro is used in UIWebView. Just a case of not enough development/testing capacity and priority to the most used applications

Comment: Ya, I found another article about that recently. It was only a matter of time. Now if we could just depend on everyone keeping their devices up too date. :-)

Comment: Ok, so I take this to mean that the Nitro engine is available even when the Safari navigation has been removed, and it has nothing to do with my problem then? I'm using iOS 5 on my iPad 2 for testing this.

Comment: Correct, the lack of Nitro would no longer be an issue. Here's an atricle: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/06/ios-5-brings-nitro-speed-to-home-screen-web-apps.ars

Comment: @Shane Well, I depend on my machines to make a living. You don't think I'd bother to update before knowing what problems to expect? (Skype 2.8 screen sharing on Lion is a current showstopper)

Comment: @Stephan: LOL. Not at all people can always depended  on to do whatever is in their best interest. That is why we can't depend on people staying up to date. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Adding this line

```
<style>
/*** patch for jquerymobile page flicker that was happending ***/
    .ui-page {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    } 
</style>
```

helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with:

```
<meta id="viewPortId" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This only partially works for me:

```
<style>
body .ui-page
{ 
     height: 100% !important; 
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input { outline: none; }
</style>

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
});
```

Which prevent's flickering and whitespace at the bottom of the page but notice that transitions are turned off.

Also, id's are not being used more than once which I can verify with:

```
// an id used more than once??
    var ids = new Array();
    $.each($("[id]"), function () {ids.push($(this).attr("id"));});

    var matches, val1;
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        matches = 0;
        val1 = new RegExp(ids[i], "i");
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < ids.length; i2++) {
            if (ids[i].length == ids[i2].length && val1.test(ids[i2]) == true)
                matches++;
        }
        if (matches > 1)
            alert("This id was used more than once: " + ids[i]);
    }
```

Have also tried:

```
$.extend($.mobile, {
        metaViewportContent: "width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    });
```

And loading the page into the DOM and only once that is complete doing the transition as so:

```
var promise = $.mobile.loadPage(url, {
        pageContainer : $("body")
    });
    promise.done(function () {
        var newPage = $("body [data-role='page']:last").attr("id");
        $.mobile.changePage($("#" + newPage));
    });
```

I'm still getting the flickering on page transitions.

---

the answer.... [jquery mobile page flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933758/jquery-mobile-page-flicker)

Comment: I checked, and it does indeed seem to have something to do with the fact that the page is taller than the screen. But what is the solution? BTW, it is all pages that are "too" tall that get this, no listviews or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the suggestions actually solved the problem, at least not for me. However, finally it has been fixed in the latest stable version of jQuery mobile (1.1.0), so the problem is finally gone! I just had to go in and change the global transition back to slide, because they set it to fade:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.extend($.mobile, {
        defaultPageTransition: 'slide'
    });
});
```

Hope this helps someone else who perhaps hadn't noticed the update.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following **META tag** solves the issue:

```
<meta id="viewPortId" name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug. See the article in the [seaside mailing list](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/seaside/2011-October/027890.html).

Rolf van der Vleuten noticed:

- flickering can occur when using the same #id more than once in a page,
  which is not unlikely when you are using the one page template method. so
  be sure to not use #id's more than once.
- I don't know why this happens, but I found out that when my first page had
  an element that is outlined by default, flickering would occur, this was
  fixed by adding:

  input {
    outline: none;
  }

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried the input { outline: none; }, and it made no difference, and I tried a test page with only two page divs, where I checked carefully that no duplicate ids slipped in, and it still flickered when I have removed the navigation bars... (again, there is no flickering when the navigation bars are there)

Answer (score 0):

From the currently open issue, ["Slide page transition causes screen repaint on iOS 5 chromeless"](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2856), the recommendation is to comment out pageTitle.focus() from the reFocus function.

This however did not solve my problem. I found it necessary to remove both pageTitle.focus() and page.focus(), basically the entire function.

This issue (and specifically the change to the reFocus function) is also mentioned in issue [2474](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2474). It is a fix for iOS4 that did not solve my iOS5 iPad problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very very strange bug.I tried to fixed it.But failed.Finally I try to add some code to my project to avoid this issue.

If you deep into jquery mobile's page transition you would know his principle.

It loads another page's (the page you want to go) body into an element such as : .

I just add an wrapper outside of this element and make a setTimeout to delay showing this page.

I made a phonegap app in iPhone 4(ios5) and can't fix this issue.Just pray that jquery mobile team would fix this bug quickly.After spending a few days on this problem I just wanna fuxk jqm...

Answer (score 0):

This only worked partially for me

```
<style>
body .ui-page
{ 
     height: 100% !important; 
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input { outline: none; }
</style>
```

for data transition "flip" it worked but not for "slide"