# jquery mobile: duplicate IDs within pages ok?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've made a jQuery Mobile (1.0 final) app, and I am having some issues with Flickering. I know this is a defined bug currently with jQM, but I wanted to see what I could do to resolve this issue.

The thread at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860478/jquery-mobile-blinking-at-page-transitions-on-ipad) mentioned the following:

> flickering can occur when using the same #id more than once in a page,
>   which is not unlikely when you are using the one page template method.
>   so be sure to not use #id's more than once.

This is a bit ambiguous to me... Obviously because jQM does AJAX loads, multiple pages may be in the DOM at any one time. In my case, my page-level IDs are all unique, but several IDs used WITHIN the pages are not (e.g. the `data-role=content` div has the ID of `#mainPageContent` for each page).

Is this an acceptable behavior, or should my IDs be unique globally?

PS: Sorry if this is a dupe, I found a few stackoverflow posts that were similar to this question but nothing I felt really answered this specifically.

Comment: since it's all loaded into the DOM I would suspect the Id's a clashing. IMHO I would refactor the Id's for each page and make them unique to comply with HTML5 standards

Comment: thanks to both of you guys for your answers. That's what I figured was the case, I just wanted to check before I invested the time refactoring. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDs **must be unique throughout your whole jQuery Mobile website** to make sure that the same ID is not appended to the DOM as an element that already exists.

A good work-around for this (since you already have unique `data-role="page"` IDs is to change the rest of the IDs in your pages to classes:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div class="mainPageContent" data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

This way you can easily target elements with CSS/JS to make global changes to your site or target a specific page:

**GLOBAL**

```
<style>
.mainPageContent {
    color : gold;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).delegate('.mainPageContent', 'click', function () {
    //...
});
</script>
```

**PAGE SPECIFIC**

```
<style>
#home > .mainPageContent {
    color : magenta;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).delegate('#home > .mainPageContent', 'click', function () {
    //...
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

No duplicate Id's are not Okay as the Id attribute is to be a unique identifier.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements

> **3.2.3.1** ***The id attribute***
>
> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.
>
> An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes,
>   most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using
>   fragment identifiers, as a way to target an element when scripting,
>   and as a way to style a specific element from CSS.
>
> If the value is not the empty string, user agents must associate the
>   element with the given value (exactly, including any space characters)
>   for the purposes of ID matching within the element's home subtree
>   (e.g. for selectors in CSS or for the getElementById() method in the
>   DOM).
>
> Identifiers are opaque strings. Particular meanings should not be
>   derived from the value of the id attribute.
>
> This specification doesn't preclude an element having multiple IDs, if
>   other mechanisms (e.g. DOM Core methods) can set an element's ID in a
>   way that doesn't conflict with the id attribute.
>
> The id IDL attribute must reflect the id content attribute.