# jquery mobile transitions effects are weird on ipad

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile page transition effects on any button click or any event are looking weird. What should I do to make it feel better?

Comment: please add some example code you are trying, maybe http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What is *weird* about the transitions? You haven't actually stated a solvable problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do they seem to flicker a bit?

If so, there's a discussion here:
[jQuery Mobile blinking at page transitions on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860478/jquery-mobile-blinking-at-page-transitions-on-ipad)

on the topic of the iPad transition flicker.

Seems an upgrade to iOS 5.0 may solve the problem. Also, if you are running it as an app, try in Safari. The bug was supposed to have been fixed in Safari.