# Screen flickering on iPad with jquery and phonegap?

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

so i've finally got my app on my ipad but there's a slight flicker when using the navigation - i'm hoping this will disappear when i package it up but if theres a something i missing??

Heres a video a made to my partner - showing it flicker,
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxU2zexGOh8

Heres the code of my navigation and first page,

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<!--PAGE START-->
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>CPA for Newbies</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="#page2"><img src="images/1.png" width="146" height="140" />
                    <h3>Video #1</h3><p>What is CPA?</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3"><img src="images/2.png" width="146" height="140" />
                    <h3>Video #2</h3><p>List of CPA Networks</p></a></li></a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4"><img src="images/3.png" width="146" height="140" />
                    <h3>Video #3</h3><p>Sign up for CPA Networks</p></a></li></a></li>
            <li><a href="#page5"><img src="images/4.png" width="146" height="140" />
                    <h3>Video #4</h3><p>CPA Types</p></a></li></a></li>
            <li><a href="#page6"><img src="images/5.png" width="146" height="140" />
                    <h3>Video #5</h3><p>Keyword Research</p></a></li></a></li>
            <li><a href="#page7"><img src="images/6.png" width="146" height="140" />
                    <h3>Video #6</h3><p>Landing Pages</p></a></li></a></li>
            <li><a href="#page8"><img src="images/7.png" width="146" height="140" />
                    <h3>Video #7</h3><p>Promoting Your Site</p></a></li></a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>MachuPicchuMobile.com</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<!--PAGE START-->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>CPA for Newbies</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <h1>Video #1</h1>
        <video controls width="auto" height="auto">
        <source src="videos/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <h3>What CPA Is And Why You Will Want To Get Into It</h3>   
        <p>CPA, also known as Cost Per Action is a great way for publishers like you to make money.  The way you make money with CPA is if the traffic you send takes a specific action, whether it's filling out a zip code, email address, or a form.  For advertisers it's a great way to build leads and many advertisers are willing to pay you anywhere from $1, $15 or more just to get a lead.  The nice thing about CPA is that you don't have to sell anything to make money.</p>             
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">        
    <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page8" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="bottom" data-theme="a"                    data-inline="true">Previous</a></li>

            <li><a href="#page" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="bottom" data-theme="a" 
                data-inline="true">Home</a></li>

            <li><a href="#page3" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="bottom" data-theme="a"                        data-inline="true">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860478/jquery-mobile-blinking-at-page-transitions-on-ipad

Comment: jQuery Mobile is on version 1.3.1 - you seem to be using 1.0 - have you tried updating to the latest version? You'll need to update jQuery to 1.9.1 as well.