# Phonegap / jquery mobile slide transition not workign properly on first call

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an awkward visual glitch.  I want a nice transition when changing pages on an app.
Unfortunately, the first time I change to another page, instead of sliding the current page out and the new page in, the current page is immediately replaced by the new page and then slides out.  When the first page is out of view, the new page is shown.  However, the second time around, it works like a charm!

This is running on iphone with jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap

I made a video to help clarify the issue: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ybvzh_wTnSE

```
    <body style="background-color: #000;">
        <div id="container" style="display:none;">
            <div id="side-menu" style="display:none;">
                <div id="header_top"></div>
                <a href="#dives" onclick="showdives();"><div id="header_dives" class="selected"></div></a>
                <div id="header_spacer1"></div>
                <a href="#explore" onclick="showexplore();"><div id="header_explore"></div></a>
                <div id="header_spacer2"></div>
                <a href="#search" onclick="showsearch();"><div id="header_search"></div></a>
                <div id="header_spacer3"></div>
                <a href="#settings" onclick="showsettings();"><div id="header_settings"></div></a>
                <div id="header_bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="slide_mask">
                <!-- START of LOGIN page -->
                <div data-role="page" id="login">           
                    <div id="home_frame">
                        <div id="home_logo"></div>
                        <div id="home_fblogin" onclick="login()"></div>
                        <div class="home_login">
                            <p>Email: <input type="text"  name="user[email]" size="30"/></p>
                            <p>Password: <input type="password"  name="user[password]" size="30"/></p>
                            <button onclick="show_page_home();">LOGIN</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END of LOGIN page -->

                <!-- START of LOGIN page -->
                <div data-role="page" id="dives" class="right_pane">    
                        <p>My dives !</p>       
                </div><!-- /content -->
                <div data-role="page" id="explore" class="hidden right_pane">   
                        <p>My explore !</p>     
                </div><!-- /content -->
                <div data-role="page" id="search" class="hidden right_pane">    
                        <p>My search !</p>      
                </div><!-- /content -->
                <div data-role="page" id="settings" class="hidden right_pane">  
                        <p>My settings !</p>
                        <button onclick="logout_db();">logout</button>      
                </div><!-- /content -->
                <!-- END of LOGIN page -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="log"></div>
        <div id="data"></div>
    </body>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
    body {margin: 0; font: 18px Helvetica; text-align: center; background-color: #000; background: url(../img/bg_big.png) repeat;
        -webkit-user-select: none;  /* prevent copy paste for all elements */
        }
    #container { width:320px; height:460px; overflow: hidden;}

    input{ -webkit-user-select: text;  /* enable copy paste for elements with this class */}
    a {-webkit-user-select: none;  /* prevent copy paste for all elements */}
    span {-webkit-user-select: none;  /* prevent copy paste for all elements */}

    #side-menu {z-index: 1000 !important; position: fixed; height: 460px; width: 56.5px; background: url(../img/bg_big.png) no-repeat; display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
    #header_top {background: url(../img/header/header_top.png) no-repeat; background-size: 56.5px 48.96px; width: 56.5px; height: 48.96px; display: block;}
    #header_dives {background: url(../img/header/dives.png) no-repeat; background-size: 56.5px 51.75px; width: 56.5px; height: 51.75px; display: block;}
    #header_dives.selected{background: url(../img/header/dives_selected.png) no-repeat;}
    #header_spacer1{background: url(../img/header/header_space1.png) no-repeat; background-size: 56.5px 13.9px; width: 56.5px; height: 13.9px; display: block;}
    #header_explore{background: url(../img/header/explore.png) no-repeat; background-size: 56.5px 51.75px; width: 56.5px; height: 51.75px; display: block;}
    #header_explore.selected{background: url(../img/header/explore_selected.png) no-repeat;}
    #header_spacer2{background: url(../img/header/header_space2.png) no-repeat; background-size: 56.5px 15.33px; width: 56.5px; height: 15.33px; display: block;}
    #header_search{background: url(../img/header/search.png) no-repeat; background-size: 56.5px 51.75px; width: 56.5px; height: 51.75px; display: block;}
    #header_search.selected{background: url(../img/header/search_selected.png) no-repeat;}
    #header_spacer3{background: url(../img/header/header_space3.png) no-repeat; background-size: 56.5px 17.73px; width: 56.5px; height: 17.73px; display: block;}
    #header_settings{background: url(../img/header/settings.png) no-repeat; background-size: 56.5px 51.75px; width: 56.5px; height: 51.75px; display: block;}
    #header_settings.selected{background: url(../img/header/settings_selected.png) no-repeat;}
    #header_bottom{background: url(../img/header/header_bottom.png) no-repeat; background-size: 56.5px 160px; width: 56.5px; height: 160px; display: block;}

    .hidden {display: none;}
    .right_pane{width: 263.5px !important; background: url(../img/right_bg.png) no-repeat; background-size:263.5px 460px; width: 263.5px; height: 460px; left: 56.5px !important;}
    #slide_mask{ display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 56.5px;  width: 263.5px; height: 460px; top: 0;}
```

and the bit of JS:

```
    ///////////////////////////////////
    //MENU MECHANICS
    ///////////////////////////////////

    function showdives(){
        $("#side-menu .selected").removeClass("selected");
        $("#header_dives").addClass("selected");
    }

    function showexplore(){
        $("#side-menu .selected").removeClass("selected");
        $("#header_explore").addClass("selected");
    }
    function showsearch(){
        $("#side-menu .selected").removeClass("selected");
        $("#header_search").addClass("selected");
    }
    function showsettings(){
        $("#side-menu .selected").removeClass("selected");
        $("#header_settings").addClass("selected");
    }
```

The onclick methods only add/remove the "selected" class to/from the menu items.

Comment: Nice video and explanation of the problem. Your issue is probably in your Javascript, so you should include that code as well.

Comment: If you are doing a $.mobile.changePage() in your handlers as well as putting the page ID in the href attribute on the link, I think that might explain it. Use changePage() or the href attribute, but not both ?

Comment: Hi john - nope i'm only using the href :/

Comment: done :) as you can see it's straightforward...

Comment: also transitions "pop" and "flip" work like a charm

Comment: UPDATE: on Android slide works like a charm...

Comment: Hello Alexander did you managed to sort out this issue?

Comment: more or less :) I pushed a few fixes on jqm that were added to the master trunk, and a buch of ppl added more fixes and since them it's more or less fixed bu stillvery average ... on Android for instance I deactivated transitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe people refer to this as "flickering", so you'll have better results when you search for that. After looking around, it looks like your problem is common on android and can be solved by adding the following CSS:

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Here are a few references:

- http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2011/07/14/eliminating-annoying-flicker-transitions-with.html
- [Flickering when navigating between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953753/flickering-when-navigating-between-pages)
- https://forum.jquery.com/topic/performance-of-jquery-mobile-on-android-2-2-and-2-3-flickering

Comment: Hi Spike - tried but it's not it :( I actually don't think it's flickering :/

Comment: Hmm... Sorry I don't know then. Maybe something with the android emulator? Does it do the same thing in iOS?

Comment: I only have the issie on iOS - android is fine (and in both cases emu and device behave the same)

Comment: Gotcha. I don't really know what else to suggest then... If I were you, I'd just start from scratch and begin adding in each piece of code bit by bit to figure out exactly which part of it is causing the glitch.

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I and my friends are using  JQuery 1.2.

The way to solve this issue was to put data-transition="none". Maybe this cannot appear mobile

style that much, but works and delete the flickering problem.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but even worse, when wrapping a Jquery mobile app in Phonegap. Not only were the page transitions flickering, but the UI was completely broken. I used Jquery 1.8 and Jquery mobile 1.2 in this app.

I have tried most of the solutions suggested here on SO, but nothing worked. Then I found  [this](http://outof.me/fixing-flickers-jumps-of-jquery-mobile-transitions-in-phonegap-apps/) solution by Piotr Walczyszyn, and everything worked like a dream! Highly recommended for anyone using Jquery mobile and Phonegap together.