# Flickering issue while navigating between pages using multipage template in jQueryMobile + PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, css, cordova

I have been trying to fix an issue of page getting flickered twice when navigating between pages. I have tried adding the following css

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

After adding this css code, the behavior is still unpredictable. Initially there is no flickering but after few clicks it starts flickering.

Can anyone please suggest a proper solution for this.

Comment: if you are using fixed header in jquery mobile there is a high chance of getting such issues releated with flickering.

Comment: I am not a cordova programmer, but I have trouble believing there's enough information here to reproduce the problem. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Does this happen when you view the pages during development, or only on when viewed on a mobile device? If so, which ones? What background images are you using? Can you provide a small example which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

JQM it's know to have issue with Cordova Phonegap, the main one it's really slow and paginating can put out troble like flickring, missing animations etc.

You can try another framework like jQT (jQTouch) or the new Intel AppFramework (not as fancy has jQT but really fast).

Also a really good (full app avaible in stores) start it's the app made by Andrew Trice that use different libraries: https://github.com/triceam/Fresh-Food-Finder

Btw there's no winner framework when using Cordova / Phonegap it depends on what You are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [Flickering when navigating between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953753/flickering-when-navigating-between-pages/16989794#16989794)

You can try adding the viewport meta tag as this solved it for me: